# Why does python -c "print float(7/3)" print out 2.0

Tags: python, types, formatting

```
python -c "print float(7/3)"
```

prints out 2.0 on my computer. What am i doing wrong?

This is what I am using:

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
```

Comment: If you want to use python -c for a command line calculator, I suggest you check out pythonpy (https://github.com/russell91/pythonpy). You can do the above as : py 7/3 => 2.3333333

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`7/3` is integer division on Python 2 and thus returns `2` (an `int`). Then you convert that to a `float`, which gives `2.0`.

You probably wanted `float(7)/3`, `7/float(3)`, `7.0/3` or `7/3.0`.

Also note that you can do `from __future__ import division` so that division is floating-point by default (you then use `//` for integer division).

Comment: Good explanation. What the OP probably _wanted_ was `print float(7)/3`. (Or, more simply, `7.0/3`.)

Comment: @ohmusama: No, it _floors_. `7/-3` is `-3`, not `-2`.

Comment: ah, then that is special handling for python that I was not aware of. I would have expected it to work like other languages. I wonder why they decided on that route?

Comment: you can also do `7./3` - very similar, just showing the 0 is optional

Comment: Excellent answer @Veedrac and others, thanks! I did a bit of research and found out that the "from __future__ import" will port implementations from future versions of Python to the current version. Does anybody know if Python 3 implements floating point division by default? Wouldn't this break compatibility in a lot of programs?

Comment: Yes, Python 3 broke compatibility in a lot of ways but is consequently a better language.

Comment: @ohmusama From the BDFL himself: http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html